# I create the defined names but i need to know how to use it (caxlsx gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, formula, xlsx, caxlsx

With https://github.com/caxlsx/caxlsx gem I'm trying to access defined names created dynamically over iteration with an `each_with_index` array method and giving each one with a name like "piece-0", "piece-1", "piece-3"... etc. On the file, the names are correctly created but I need the formula for sum many calling them by the name.

```
she.add_row ["Total","",""] + ["--the sum of cells by name must be here--"]
```

**I create the names but I need to know how to use them.**

Answer (score 0):

**Solved!**

Solution was build a string that concatenate and reference the cells.

something like this.

```
build_string = ""
cellposition = "10"
cells.each do |cell|
  build_string = @alphabet_with_letters[position_that_i_want] + cellposition + ":"
  cellposition = cellposition.to_i
  cellposition += 1
  cellposition == cellposition.to_s
end

#then use this where you need to call it
"=SUM(#{build_string.chop})"
```